# GeoDjango Distance() Annotation on Related Model

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have a `Profile` class which is a OneToOne with `Location` model. Every profile has one and only location.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOne(Profile)
    point = PointField()
```

In one of my views, I display a list of profiles. For example, I first find profiles with locations and then find associated profiles.

```
ref_location = Point(0,0) # point to calculate distances from
locations = Location.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(ref_location, D(m=50 * 1000))) \
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(pk__in=locations.values('profile_id'))
```

What I would want is to be able to know the distance to each of these profile instances, e.g. I want to do something like:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(pk__in=locations.values('profile_id'))\
.annotate(distance=Distance('location__point', ref_location))
```

and then iterate over

```
for p in profiles:
    print(p.distance.km)
```

Which is **not possible**

What I can do is `annotate` the `locations` instead, which isn't much use, because in the template I loop over `profiles`, not `locations`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) (for Django version >= 1.11) to compose this query:

```
locations = Location.objects.filter(
    point__distance_lte=(OuterRef('ref_location'), D(m=50 * 1000))
).annotate(distance=Distance(OuterRef('point'), ref_location))

profiles = Profile.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Subquery(locations.values('profile_id')
).annotate(distance=Subquery(locations.values('distance')))
```

Or for Django version < 1.11 you can compose this query as follows:

```
locations = Location.objects.filter(
    point__distance_lte=(ref_location), D(m=50 * 1000))
).annotate(distance=Distance('point', ref_location))

profiles = Profile.objects.filter(
    pk__in=locations.values('profile_id')
).annotate(distance=locations.values('distance'))
```

The point is that you annotate the distance to the `Location` objects and then you annotate that distance to the appropriate profile.