# How to get distinct results when ordering by a related annotated field?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is a Django (2.2) project using Python (3.7). Given the following models, how would I get distinct results in the query below?

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)


class Location(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, ...)
    point = PointField()


class ProfileService(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, ...)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, ...)
```

Here's the query I have so far which works but I end up with duplicate 'ProfileService' objects:

```py
service = Service.objects.get(id=1)

qs = (
  ProfileService.objects
  .filter(service=service)
  .annotate(distance=Distance('profile__location__point', self.point))
  .order_by('distance')
)
```

If I add `.distinct('profile')` it obviously fails with `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`.

I have a feeling that the solution lies in using `__in` but I need to keep the annotated `distance` field.

## Further explanation

To help illustrate further, the lists below represent dummy data that will reproduce the issue:

```py
services = [
    { 'id': 1, 'service': 'A', ... },
    { 'id': 2, 'service': 'B', ... },
]

users = [
    { 'id': 1, 'username': 'Jane Doe', 'email': 'jane@test.com', ... },
    { 'id': 2, 'username': 'John Doe', 'email': 'john@test.com', ... },
]

profiles = [
    { 'id': 1, 'user': 1, ... },
    { 'id': 2, 'user': 2, ... },
]

locations = [
    { 'id': 1, 'profile': 1, 'point': 'X', ... },
    { 'id': 2, 'profile': 1, 'point': 'Y', ... },
    { 'id': 3, 'profile': 2, 'point': 'Z', ... },
]
# 'point' would normally contain actual Point data.
# Letters (XYZ) just intended to represent unique Point data.

profile_services = [
    { 'id': 1, 'profile': 1, 'service': 1 },
    { 'id': 2, 'profile': 1, 'service': 2 },
    { 'id': 3, 'profile': 2, 'service': 1 },
]
```

It is the 'Location' objects that cause the duplications in the 'qs' queryset above (if a 'Profile' has only 1 'Location' associated with it, there is no duplicate result in 'qs'), however the user does need to keep the ability to provide multiple locations, we just need the closest.

## Progress

Following the advice from 'Ivan Starostin', I have put together the following using subqueries:

```py
locations = (
    Location.objects
    .filter(profile=OuterRef('profile'))
    .annotate(distance=Distance('point', self.point))
    .order_by('distance')
)

qs = (
    ProfileService.objects
    .filter(service=service)
    .filter(profile__id__in=Subquery(locations.values('profile_id')[:1]))
    .annotate(distance=Subquery(locations.values('distance')[:1]))
)
```

Now this solves the issue of duplicate results but it loses the annotated 'distance' value which should be annotated against the applicable ProfileService query object. Not sure if this is going in the right direction or not (any pointers would be greatly appreciated), I just want to avoid pulling the data into Python memory to get rid of the duplicates.

I have been refering to the following post too but the accepted answer refuses to work in my queryset: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51515229/2814610)

Comment: Have you tried **`.distinct()`** ? (without field name)

Comment: Thanks @ArakkalAbu, yes I have. It has no affect on the duplicates.

Comment: How can you end up with duplicate `ProfileService` objects? That's not possible with the query you're showing. The only possible thing is you end up with multiple `ProfileService` objects with the **same** `Profile`.

Comment: Are you  trying to find the nearest or farthest point to each ProfileService?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, I am just ordering by distance from a given point (this works as expected).

Comment: Then there **must** be duplicate ProfileService with different points in the resultset.

Comment: Sorry @IvanStarostin, you are right. There will more than likely be multiple 'Location' records for each 'Profile'. I just want the closest 'ProfileService' record from a given point if said 'Profile' has more than one 'Location' entry.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#limiting-the-subquery-to-a-single-row

Comment: Thanks @IvanStarostin, I'll have a read through now.

Comment: @dirkgroten Apologies, I have only just seen your comment. You are correct, each Profile can have multiple ProfileService's but 'profileservice.service' is unique per Profile.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "duplicate". The query you're showing **cannot** contain two times the same `ProfileService` (i.e. two rows with the same primary key). Please explain your "duplicates".

Comment: @dirkgroten, thanks for the response. I have expanded my question (please see the 'Further explanation' section).

Comment: Hello did you tried something like this ?
ProfileService.objects.order_by('profile__location__point').distinct('profile')

Comment: @Stéphane Thanks for the help but that just gives the same 'SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions' error.

Comment: Sorry for that =/
I made the same dbb as you and manage to do what I think you want to do with this :
`serv = Service.objects.get(id=1)`
`ProfileService.objects.filter(service=serv).order_by('profile__location__point').first()`

NB: In my database the value of "point" is an integer

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane I did try your solution but it didn't work. I need to keep the annotated calculated Distance value in the query to provide the distance functionality.