# filter on distance by using pointfield

Tags: django, geodjango, django-filter

I want to set the filter on distance by using the point field

i have model shop

```
class Shop(models.Model):
     distance = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
     Shop_location = models.PointField(null=True)
```

the shop can define a distance from its location under which its id show to another user.
when the user shares its location and the user able to see the shop which satisfies the condition.
the condition is that the distance calculated between the user and shop less than or equal to the distance given by the shop

Comment: Also similar:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506916/geodjango-distance-annotation-on-related-model/51515229#51515229
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609729/geodjango-filter-by-distance-from-a-model-field

Comment: but I am not able to understand please make   code for me  I have only one model shop and I want to make a template for the user with a map where they share loction

Comment: Django filter location distance with dynamic radius it is work when both data save but in my case, I want to use one data save and one is random it  is not saved

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tested it but i think this might work
you can do it by `Distance` object and lookup, geodjango [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-lookups) explain it well. also you need django `F` object to get each row's distance value. i have also assumed that your distance that you save in shop model is in `kilometer` or `km`

```py
from django.db.models import F
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D


user_location = Point() # your user location should be a standard `Point` object as well

# F object will get each shop's distance
# this query will get you all shops that their distance is less than or equal 
# of the distance between shop_location and user_location
in_distance_shops = Shop.objects.filter(shop_location__distance_lte=(user_location, D(km=F("distance"))))
```

Comment: how the user can share the current location then the shop will print

Comment: usaully user will post a longtitude and latituder of a location you then will receive these coordination and cast it to django's `Point` object after that you can use this point object.

Comment: I am getting error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'F'